# Fairly complex SQL statement using inner join (I presume)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm having trouble figuring out how to write an SQL query to return results from the following table structure.

The first thing I do is get a list of clients that have a status equal to 1 by:

```
SELECT * FROM clients WHERE status=1
```

Then I need to get all user email addresses  that belong to a client. My plan was to loop through the results of the query above and running multiple queries for each client. As you can see from the table 'client_user_list' a single user can belong to multiple clients.

I tried doing something like this:

```
SELECT emailaddress 
FROM users 
INNER JOIN client_user_list ON users.user_id = client_user_list.user_id 
WHERE users.client_id = 1
```

But it failed. As you can see I'm a total novice when it comes to this stuff. Any help would be appreciated, or feel free to point me to an appropriate resource to learn more. I've looked, but I haven't found anything that covers something complex like this.

Additional info: Using foreign keys there are relationships between clients <-> client_user_list and client_user_list <-> users

```
clients:
|---------------------------------------|
|  client_id  |  client_name   | status |
|---------------------------------------|
|      1      |    John Doe    |    1   |
|      2      |    James Doe   |    0   |
|---------------------------------------|

client_user_list:
|----------------------|
| client_id  | user_id |
|----------------------|
|     1      |    5    |
|     2      |    6    |
|     1      |    6    |
|----------------------|

users:
|---------------------------------------|
|   user_id   |       emailaddress      |
|---------------------------------------|
|      5      |     notan@email.com     |
|      6      |     afake@email.com     |
|---------------------------------------|
```

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: In general, you are better off getting your results with a single query, rather than executing two separate query statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is your only problem, since you didn't specify what the exact problem is, but the `WHERE`-clause of your query contains an error. You query should be changed into this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT emailaddress 
FROM users 
INNER JOIN client_user_list ON users.user_id = client_user_list.user_id 
WHERE client_user_list.client_id = 1
```

The `users` table does not have a field called `client_id`, the `client_user_list` table does.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. That is absolutely an issue in this example, and has been fixed. But that hasn't fixed my problem.

Comment: @Tyler, then what is the problem that remains?

Comment: I just can't figure out how to go from the client id I get from the first query, to getting a list of email address from the users table for that client.

Comment: @Tyler, your current query should give you that (if you replace the `1` with the client id of course).

Comment: Problem is elsewhere then. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Problem solved. I was using the ` character around users.user_id. I fixed the initial problem you pointed out, removed those characters and now it works. Really Appreciate it! Also... I freaking love stackoverflow.

Comment: Add several more clients with various statuses, plus corresponding data in the other tables, and you will see this query does *not* give correct results per OP. Check other correct answers which deserve credit.

Comment: @WarrenT, I added a distinct, which should deal with your concern I think. In this case though, duplicate e-mailadresses would mean wrong data since a user and a client shouldn't be coupled multiple times. I know this could all be done in one query, but I wanted to stay as close to the OP's query as possible.

Comment: My concern was more that it *should* be done in one query, such as the other answers provide.  A two stage solution is prone to a variety of issues. I would guess Tyler might not understand how to do the three-way join. So my preference would be to teach the best solution. But at least we can all now understand the rationale behind your answer. And Tyler has both types of answer, which is gives him both avenues. So good job to all.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the clients with `status = 1` **and** their users with only **one** query, by joining all three tables:

```
select clients.client_id, clients.client_name, users.user_id, users.emailaddress
from clients
inner join client_user_list on client_user_list.client_id = clients.client_id
inner join users on client_user_list.user_id = users.user_id
where clients.status = 1
order by clients.client_id, users.user_id
```

Answer (score 2):

The following command should resolve this issue
I hope it is userful.

```
select distinct use.emailaddress
from clients cli
inner join client_user_list cul on (cli.client_id=cul.client_id)
inner join users use on (cul.user_id = use.user_id)
where cli.status = 1
```